# Have a resistor on for 400 ms then change path to a lower resistance

Tags: transistors, capacitor, integrated-circuit, delay

I'm building a guitar effect with a [PT2399](http://www.princeton.com.tw/Portals/0/Product/PT2399_1.pdf) IC. This IC needs a 2.2 kΩ resistor connected to pin 6 for the first 400 ms after power is applied. After that 400 ms, it can be as low as 100 Ω.

I'd like to go that low, but still have that larger resistance in place for that first 400 ms, and I'm struggling to find a good way to do so.

Could it be done with an NPN switch and a capacitor?

(For anyone interested, [here is an analysis of the PT2399 by Electrosmash](https://www.electrosmash.com/pt2399-analysis), explaining the requirement for greater than 2 kΩ from pin 6 to ground, during the 400 ms after power on.)

Comment: Can you draw the output stage of what you want to do this with the tool?

Comment: Do you have a micro controller, or is this all analog?

Comment: @Jasper which resisistor in the PT2399 do you want to switch?

Comment: It's all analog. Pin6 actually gives a 2.5v dc and controls delay time by changing the resistor that is connected from pin6 to ground.

Comment: The Electrosmash link gives great insight to the IC operation but makes the question suspect now.  The echo Resistance controlled VCO needs to be > 2k on power up to prevent a CMOS latch-up effect but after this needs R from 100 Ohms to 28 kOhms to control f from 22 MHz down to 2 MHz which induces an echo delay from 32 ms to 342 ms.  So your request is ONLY for power on sequence and not in normal operation.  Since Pin 6 is the inverting input to a CMOS OP Amp with 2.5V on + side. I think a large cap from Pin6 to Pin 2 would suppress a latchup  by nulling the diff. input voltage on power up OK?

Comment: Tony, that's right, it's only for the 400 ms power on sequence. I'll try a large cap (how large? Would a 10 uF cap do?). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If this 'resistor' is in a feedback pathway, the ADG1611 should do the trick. With leakage in the nA range and cross capacitance between channels at ~100pF, it should affect your audio signal very little. It also has very little charge injection when switching (which would reduce 'pop' noises).

It does vary resistance (because it contains a PMOS and NMOS transistor in parallel that are matched), but it's less than 1Ω in most cases.

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG1611_1612_1613.pdf

Or an NMOS transistor could work also

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHnHSQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This design is incorrect and only changes the echo delay from 34 ms to 32 ms when it should allow a delay of 100 ms ~ 300ms by allowing the resistance to be increased. R3 defeats this.  Pls fix or delete.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmFGCE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should be about right.  If you don't have 1V available directly, adjust C1 accordingly.

Comment: if you don't have 1V available you could make it by  connecting R1 ro ground and adding 2M from C1 to +5V  also the question calls for 2.2K not 400 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a 555 timer like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvAEjL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>